# Oracle Date formatting "2009-02-13T11:46:40+00:00"

Tags: oracle, date, formatting

I've had some brilliant help before and I'm hoping you can get me out of a hole again.

I've got a date coming in from a web service in this format:
2009-02-13T11:46:40+00:00

which to me looks like standard UTC format.

I need to insert it into an Oracle database, so I'm using to_date() on the insert.  Problem is, I cant get a matching formatting string for it and keep getting "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string" errors.

I know its a fairly trivial problem but for some reason I cannot get it to accept the right format string.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks :)

Gareth

Comment: What mask are you supplying to TO_DATE()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE('2009-02-13T11:46:40+00:00', 'T', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM') AS DATE)
FROM    dual
```

Answer (score 8):

You can directly convert it to a TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE datatype.

```
select
  to_timestamp_tz('2009-02-13T11:46:40+00:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
from
 dual

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2009-02-13T11:46:40+00:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
13-FEB-09 11.46.40.000000000 AM +00:00
```

(I'm assuming the input string is using a 24-hour clock since there is no AM/PM indicator.)

If you want to convert that to a simple DATE, you can, but it will lose the time zone information.

Comment: Dave, this is brilliant cheers - I cant use a TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE datatype though as its not my database. However, that would be the preferred solution.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for this, Dave.  The double quotes around the "T" was the magic incantation I needed to get the conversion to work.  :)

Answer (score 1):

To import date in specified format you can set `nls_date_format`.

Example:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

This way your SQL statements can be shorter (no casts). For various mask look at [Datetime Format Models](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)